# How to remove Double Quotes from a CSV File insertion into an SQL DB

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, csv

I'm receiving multiple `CSV` files but some of them have every value inside a double quoting, which breaks every further processing inside SQL.

[image: Data Example]

The application already has a method that takes some of the CSV Files (based on their name), reads them line by line and appends a value to the end of the String to create a new column, and then, writing to a new file, without replacing the old one.

I thought about re-using that method and applying it to every file, but instead of appending new values to each line, removing the **`"`** characters, this should work just fine, but since some of the files are really big (Some of them around 1GB) i'd like to avoid unnecessary performance issues.

Is there a better way to replace, delete or ignore every **`"`** character, either in Java or during/after the SQL insertion?

Comment: Give some sample data..

Comment: How are you importing the data? With SSIS? If so, that supports quoted identifiers. With a `BULK INSERT`? If so, are you specifing the `FIELDQUOTE`, `FORMAT` and using SQL Server 2017+? If you are using 2016- and `BULK INSERT`, then it does **not** support quoted fields and I suggest looking at an alternative method.

Comment: @Larnu We are using `BULK INSERT` with SQL Server 2014 so im afraid it will need to be done through Java

Comment: @DineshDB I added a small peek at the data

Comment: If you're using SQL Server 2014 then you will need to use something *else* to perform the insert then, @DS94 . Or, you'll need to change the delimiter in the file to something else that doesn't appear in your data (as I assume a comma (`,`) can appear in the data and why it quoted) and remove the field quotes. Unfortunately, at this time, only SQL Server  2017 and 2019 support quoted fields in CSV (or equivilent) files.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `REPLACE` the **Double Quotes (")** from your table using the following Query.

```
UPDATE TableName
SET Column1 = REPLACE(Column1,'"',''),
Column2 = REPLACE(Column2,'"','')
...
...
...
ColumnN = REPLACE(ColumnN,'"','')
```

Comment: The problem is that i don't know the column names beforehand, not even the table names, as it's generated through dynamic sql, so i guess id'd need to modify our procedures to store the column names and then apply your answer to them